# How to upload pdf in server in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, upload, jspdf

> I am working on project where onclick button there will create pdf of
>   particular DIV. I have code for createPdf and download it. Now i want
>   to move it to server rather than download it.Below is my code to
>   createPdf and download it.

```
$scope.createPdf = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{image: data,width: 500}]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
        }
    }); 
};
```

Comment: If you are using HTML5 this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: What library does the code use to make PDF?

Comment: If the pdf Library has a method for downloading, it probably has a method for creating an array buffer or blob. Post that.

Comment: im using jspdf @georgeawg